# When did modern punctuation emerge?

Tags: punctuation

Medieval punctuation was different from the one we use now; for example, Medieval punctuation included [*punctus*, *punctus versus*, and *punctus flexus*](http://www.ualberta.ca/~sreimer/ms-course/course/punc.htm).

When did their equivalent in modern English emerge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Modern punctuation, designed to
>   clarify syntactic structures rather
>   than to indicate breathings, is
>   largely a Renaissance invention,
>   developing during the first
>   generations of the printing press, and
>   codified in the eighteenth century
>   (about the same time that
>   capitalization and spelling became
>   fixed in more or less their current
>   form).
>   Among the earliest works showing
>   "modern" punctuation is Francis
>   Bacon's *Essays*. An interesting early
>   discussion of the nature of modern
>   punctuation can be found in Ben
>   Jonson's *English Grammar* (composed ca.
>   1617, printed posthumously in 1640).
>   Eighteenth- and nineteenth-century
>   punctuation practice varies
>   considerably, but tends to be "heavy";
>   current "light" punctuation is largely
>   the invention of H. G. and F. G.
>   Fowler, The King's English.

http://www.ualberta.ca/~sreimer/ms-course/course/punc.htm