# What is the origin of the '.' (full stop/period)

Tags: punctuation

What is the origin of the '.' (Full stop/period) in written English? Is it known when this sign appeared the first time in written English?

Comment: [LMGTFY: see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop). Also, the stop wasn't invented for English but well prior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When did modern punctuation emerge?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/when-did-modern-punctuation-emerge)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A full set of punctuation marks began to appear only after the invention of printing. Manuscripts were almost totally unpunctuated. The term *punctuation* itself is first recorded in 1539. *Full stop* appears about 60 years later, so it’s probably safe to say that the mark itself only became anything like widespread sometime in the sixteenth century.

Answer (score 5):

The full stop was used a long time before the sixteenth century, but didn't have the same purpose - the Anglo-Saxon Corpus 140 manuscript of the Gospel According to Saint John dates from the 11th century and uses the punctus (modern full stop), but has a broad variety of functions rather than simply marking the end of a sentence and was mainly rhetorical. The sign must therefore pre-date the 11th century, but maybe your question is more along the lines of when the full stop was first used in the way we use it today?